# Why Tomcat7 is replicating all my logs in /var/log/messages in ec2 installation

Tags: amazon-ec2, log4j, tomcat7

I have a Jersey application which uses log4j over slf4j, the application has its own log4j.xml file which configures one appender:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="dailyRollingFile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/this-app.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="${this-app.log.severity.all}" />
    <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFile" />
</root>
```

The application runs in ec2 with a typical tomcat 7 installation, by typical I mean that we never added any special configuration at container level for logging purposes.

Everything works and the log files are being created and rolled daily in the ${catalina.base}/logs folder.

However, recently someone found that all our logs are also appearing in a file:

```
/var/log/messages
```

I read the Tomcat 7 documentation and I cannot find a reference to that file, I don't want my logs to be duplicated.

**Edit:**

Found that it is not only replicating my application log entries but all the logs in the server like catalina.out, localhost_access logs, etc. Into that single file /var/log/messages which is also rolled every day based on date.

Comment: No, there isn't a symbolic link

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but is the EC2 instance using systemd (CentOS 7 for example)? If so it is possible journald grabbing the log files.

We've faced a similar issue here and have decided to stop using the console log for our application logging.

You can use journalctl -f -u tomcat to get what would once have appeared in catalina.out.

Couple of links for info:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048608

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tomcat#Logging